# Spring Boot microservices dependency

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, pom.xml, maven-dependency

In my project I have a lot of microservices. Some of the microservices are dependent on each other. for e.g. microservice X is dependent on microservice Y and currently I have that dependency in microservice X's pom.xml as below:

(microservice Y)

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
      <artifactId>integration-framework</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

I do not want to have my dependency in pom.xml because for e.g. if I change the version of Spring Boot in microservice X from 1.5.x to 2.x then it's having a ripple effect in mircoservice Y. I have to change the Spring Boot version in microservice Y as well.

Do I have any other option for e.g. service discovery?

Please kindly advise and help me.

Comment: Are you sure what you implemented is microservice as we know it? How are you deploying your components. And how are you doing the communication  between microservice X and Y?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this, if I understand correctly, by playing with pom inheritance.

Assume you have a main project with a main .pom, which is called `super pom` (let's call it **Z**), packaged as a `pom`. All your *microservices* will be in separate modules in the project, inheriting this `super pom`.

Put everything in common between **every** of you microservices in **Z**, like version properties, common dependencies, etc... and define a module section containing all your subprojects **X** and **Y**

**Z** `super pom`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <!-- if you have a parent pom on top of it -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>my.awesome.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>z</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Z</name>
    <description>Z</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging> <!-- THIS IS IMPORTANT -->

    <properties>
        <springbootVersion>2.3.2.RELEASE</springbootVersion>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- your COMMON dependencies -->
    </dependencies>

    <modules>
        <module>x</module>
        <module>y</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

**X** or **Y** `children pom`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent> <!-- MATCHING SUPER POM !! -->
        <groupId>my.awesome.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>z</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SHAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>x</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>X</name>
    <description>X</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <!-- You can only put one parent pom, and it is taken by our super pom, so we add spring-boot dependencies using dependencyManagement to solve this issue -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${springbootVersion}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- YOUR DEPS (but specific to X/Y) -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
           <!-- YOUR PLUGINS -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```